# PHP - unset array where Key is X and Value is Y

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this type of array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [fams] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array        --> I want to remove this value using its index, which is "1"
        (
            [id] => 2
            [fams] => 5
        )
)
```

I want to remove that array `[1]` entirely, using its index, so the condition is - where the ID is match, for example - `[id] => 2`
Is that possible, to remove a particular value with that specific condition?
and without looping (or any similar method that need to loop the array)

thanks in advance!

FYI - I did try to search around, but, to be honest, I'm not sure what "keyword" do I need to use.
I did try before, but I found, array_search, array_keys - and it seems those 2 are not.
I'm okay, if we need several steps, as long as it did not use "loop" method.

---update
I forgot to mention, that I'm using old **PHP 5.3**.

Comment: No, there's no way to do it without looping. Why don't you make it an associative array that uses the ID as keys?

Comment: thanks for the clarity @Barmar! :) I want to, but I can't, since, those array, is kind of "cart", so the index [0], [1]... is like an auto-increment keys, where, the item can be added / removed

Comment: Why does it have to be without looping?

Comment: since, those array, might be a big data of array. On real sample, that array, having multiple-dimension array inside it (and so on). and I do want to find another method that not weighting this old server performance.

Comment: @wandyyd a simple `for` or `foreach` loop will generally have better performance than using one of PHP's built-in `array_*` functions

Comment: @Nick thanks for your additional comment. I will use loop-method instead. :)

Comment: @wandyyd no worries. The real benefit of the `array_*` functions is readability more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) should work fine with PHP 5.3.

The downside of this approach is that `array_filter` will (internally) iterate over all your array's entries, even after finding the right one (it's not a "short-circuit" approach). But at least, it's quick to write and shouldn't make much of a difference unless you're dealing with very big arrays.

Note: you should **definitely** upgrade your PHP version anyway!

```
$array = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'id' => 0,
    'fams' => 5
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'fams' => 5
  )
);

$indexToRemove = 2;
$resultArray = array_filter($array, function ($entry) use ($indexToRemove) {
  return $entry['id'] !== $indexToRemove;
});
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/6DXjl**

Comment: thanks for your answer @Jeto! but, it seems, it didn't works against my real array. *edit - I did try using a simple array (like on my example), it works perfectly, but when I'm using real array (on my actual array, it having many values, where some of it, having another array inside it), but the structure is same, there's ID (target ID) that I want to remove (or unset)

Comment: @wandyyd Can you show an excerpt of your array (preferably by editing your question)? That should work as long as `$entry['id']` is accessible.

Comment: @wandyyd Also note that this solution doesn't alter your array in place, but returns a new one. So you can do `$array = array_filter($array, ...)` to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the key of a sub-array that has a matching `id` value (extracted using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)), and if found, [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) that element:

```
if (($k = array_search(2, array_column($array, 'id'))) !== false) {
    unset($array[$k]);
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [fams] => 5
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/n1Jef)

It should be noted that although there is no explicit loop in this code, `array_search` and `array_column` both loop through the array internally.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention, that I'm using the old PHP, 5.3. I do want to tried that method, but from what I see, it seems I need PHP 5.5 >=

Comment: @wandyyd unfortunately before 5.5 your only real option is to explicitly loop through the array. You really should look at upgrading your PHP version though, 5.3 has not been supported for a very long time...

Comment: @wandyyd You can use a polyfill for `array_column`.

Comment: @wandyyd you shouldn't accept an answer (although you can upvote) if it doesn't actually solve your problem. Take a look at Jeto's answer...

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarity! I do try to check around, and yes, seems that 5.3 is my big obstacle in this issue. I will mark your answer as accepted answer, since it's the most closest answer (sorry that I forgot to mention about PHP version before) and +1 for your additional notes :)

Comment: @Nick thanks for your latest comment, I didn't notice Jeto's answer, I'm still trying using that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column` to make `id` as index of the sub-array then use `unset`

```
$a = array_column($a, null, 'id');//new array id as index
$index = 2;// id to remove
if($a[$index]) unset($a[$index]);
print_r($a);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/ofMr7

Comment: This only gives the correct answer because index 0 has id = 0

Comment: @Nick here `index` means the `id` which OP wants to remove.

Comment: Try your code with `$index = 0`. The output is not the same as the input array would be with the first entry removed

Comment: thanks @RakeshJakhar for your answer, but it seems I can't use array_column, since I realize it's for PHP 5.5 >=